# Angular *ngFor problems on showing result

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, tags

i'm trying to show tags from user, (example when user write #name).
my code in html is this.

```
<div *ngIf="tagsArr" style="display: flex;">
 <p>
  <span>Tags: </span>
 </p>
 <p *ngFor="let tag of tagsArr"> 
   <span> {{tag}}, </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

This is the code. and the result is like:

> Tags: #name ,#name ,#name < / p >,

(without space)

Why the end tag of `</p>,` is displayed there?

I want to display the Tags like:

**Tags: #name, #name, #name**

Comment: if you see `<p>,` I suppose you have a `<p>`  string in `tagsArr`

Answer (score 1):

it shouldn't show `<p>` may be you have a `<p>` string in `tagsArr`
it work fine on my device

**.ts**

```
tagsArr = ['#tag1, #tag2, #tag3' ,'#tag4' ]
```

**.html**

```
<div *ngIf="tagsArr">
 <p>
  <span>Tags: </span>
 </p>
  <p *ngFor="let tag of tagsArr"> 
    <span> {{tag}}, </span>
  </p>
</div>
```